# Mplayer does not play sound for files recorded from dvb-c after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, mplayer, dvb

I just upgraded my system from 20.04 to 22.04. Now mplayer does not play sound for files I recorded from DVB-C anymore.
It is not a general sound problem, because for downloaded movie files from the mediathek, it works, just for the dvb-c recorded files it doesn't and it outputs:

```
/scratch/tv$ mplayer tagesschau24.Morning_Briefing_216_20220915_091801.mpeg
MPlayer 1.4 (Debian), built with gcc-11 (C) 2000-2019 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tagesschau24.Morning_Briefing_216_20220915_091801.mpeg.
libavformat version 58.76.100 (external)
MPEG-PS file format detected.
Possibly bad interleaving detected.
Use -ni option if this causes playback issues and avoid or fix the program that created the file.
MPEG: No audio stream found -> no sound.
VIDEO:  MPEG2  720x576  (aspect 3)  25.000 fps  15000.0 kbps (1875.0 kbyte/s)
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 58.134.100 (external)
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f835574f380]Requested frame threading with a custom get_buffer2() implementation which is not marked as thread safe. This is not supported anymore, make your callback thread-safe.
Selected video codec: [ffmpeg2] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-2)
==========================================================================
Load subtitles in ./
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [vdpau] 720x576 => 720x576 Planar YV12 
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 720x576 => 1024x576 Planar YV12 
V:  64.6 1610/1610  3%  1%  0.0% 0 0
```

The -ni option doesn't change anything btw.

Is this maybe related to the missing codecs.conf?

```
mplayer -V
MPlayer 1.4 (Debian), built with gcc-11 (C) 2000-2019 MPlayer Team
CPU vendor name: AuthenticAMD  max cpuid level: 13
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics     (Family: 23, Model: 1, Stepping: 0)
extended cpuid-level: 31
extended cache-info: 33579328
Detected cache-line size is 64 bytes
CPUflags:  MMX: 1 MMX2: 1 3DNow: 0 3DNowExt: 0 SSE: 1 SSE2: 1 SSE3: 1 SSSE3: 1 SSE4: 1 SSE4.2: 1 AVX: 1
Compiled with runtime CPU detection.
get_path('codecs.conf') -> '/home/juergen/.mplayer/codecs.conf'
Reading optional codecs config file /home/juergen/.mplayer/codecs.conf: No such file or directory
Reading optional codecs config file /etc/mplayer/codecs.conf: No such file or directory
Using built-in default codecs.conf.
init_freetype
```

Comment: Try (re-)installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much @ChanganAuto. If you like, you can create an answer. I woud accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to at least one missing codec for the format you're trying to reproduce.

You can install or, perhaps in this case reinstall the codecs package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: Btw. some different but related thing. Now audio works, but for some reason, mencoder crashes if I want to record from dvbc, while mplayer can display the same channels without problems. Do you know what that the reason could be? or should I create another post here?

Comment: Better to ask another question, add logs if available, and maybe open a bug report.

Comment: Already had a look at mencoder's last words. Thought it left me some greetings, before it dies, but it looks it just runs on a "segmentation fault".